# Why there is no operator-> in std::array

Tags: c++, stdarray

I am writing a `std::array` class as a little exercise, during which I found out that `std::array` does not implement `operator->`.
Thus for arrays the following is allowed

```cpp
struct S { int s; };
S c[2];
c->s = 2;
```

but for `std::array` this is not possible

```cpp
struct S { int s; };
std::array<S,2> cpp;
// cpp->s = 2;  // does not compile
```

which makes a `std::array` not fully compatible to a C-array.
Is there a reason for this decision.

---

*(I expected harsh reactions, but I am surprised how fast they came.)*

Clearly, as we know, arrays are not pointers but just decay to them. The problem in C++ is not that they decay, but that they decay automatically. If one on purpose uses `->` syntax for a `std::array`, this is most likely bad design, but not a problem.

Even with an `operator->` the `std::array` would be something like a first-class-citizien in C++ (which is an array not).

C++ is not a language where the user shall be prevented from every harm.

Comment: Looks like an obscure syntax that's not worth to keep for an array wrapper. The full compatibility is undesired (if they acted the same, `std::array` would be unnecessary).

Comment: If you learn one thing today, please let be that **arrays are not pointers**.  They may decay to them in a lot of places, but an array is not actually a pointer.  `std::array`s behavior of not acting like a pointer is a good thing, as it gets us away from code like this.

Comment: "C arrays" don't have that operator, either. `c->x = 2;` is equivalent to `(&c[0])->x = 2;`. That `std::array`s don't implicitly convert like this is a feature, not a bug.

Comment: `std::array` is meant to be without the poor qualities of raw arrays. That includes emerging properties of those qualities as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`c->s` works because a raw array like `c[2]`, automatically *decays* to a pointer in expressions.

So `c->s` is equivalent to `c[0].s`.

An object such as `std::array` does not decay to a pointer and provides no `->` or `T*` overloads, hence `cpp->s` does not work.

---

> *`std::array` [is] not fully compatible to a C-array*

Fortunately not! It's an array-like *object* that solves many issues associated with raw arrays.

Accessing the array's first element like `c->s` might be nice and concise, but readability of it is questionable, in fact many people consider array decay a problem rather than a feature.

Also CppCoreGuidelines [admits](https://isocpp.github.io/CppCoreGuidelines/CppCoreGuidelines#p4-ideally-a-program-should-be-statically-type-safe) array-to-pointer-decay is a problem area:

> Ideally, a program would be completely statically (compile-time) type
> safe. Unfortunately, that is not possible. Problem areas:
>
> - unions
> - casts
> - **array decay**
> - range errors
> - narrowing conversions

`std::array` addresses the idiosyncrasy stemming from C, by prohibiting it.

> *C++ is not a language where the user shall be prevented from every harm* ...

True. As they say, "when your hammer is C++, everything becomes a thumb".
But this doesn't mean we can't do anything about it, one problem area at a time. This is what `std::array` does to raw arrays, `std::unique_ptr` to owning pointers, `nullptr` to `NULL`, etc.

Answer (score 1):

> Why there is no operator-> in std::array

Because arrays aren't a form of indirection, nor does an array have members, so providing an indirecting member access operator would make little sense.

Using operator-> with arrays is highly misleading (in my opinion) and it only works as a side-effect of array-to-pointer decay. ~50% of the reason why `std::array` is used in the first place is to avoid unintentional array-to-pointer decay.

Answer (score 1):

You probably wanted to say

```
c->s = 2;
```

instead of `c->x`. When `c` is declared as an array, then the variable `c` is just a pointer to the first element `c[0]` of that array, which is a struct in your case. Applying the operator `->` to that pointer `c->s` is the same as `c[0].s`.
When using an `std::array` the variable `cpp` does not represent a pointer to the first element. Therefore the arrow operator doesn't make any sense here.